# How DOMXpath clicks a row on dynamic table depending on 2 innerText values in the table?

Tags: html, domxpath

I'm working on an automation project using Automation Anywhere.
I would like to click on a row in dynamically generated table using Object Cloning but not sure how to do it.

For example:

Number | Color | Size   | Item  | Status

55     | Red   | Small  | Car   | Active

243    | White | Medium | Plane | Stop

542    | Blue  | Medium | Plane | Active

787    | Green | Big    | Bike  | Stop

The item Plane may appear 2 times in the table with different status, but I would like to only click on the row Item=Plane, Status=Active.

How do I check these 2 conditions in DOMXpath?
This is the DOMXpath screenshot of clicking the cell but it's not always accurate.

//tbody[@id='dataTableBody']/tr[3]/td[4]/span[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2uRCS.jpg)
The position of row to click differs based on search result.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2uRCS.jpg)

Comment: please add your table html

Answer (score 1):

Thanks Kresimir for giving some ideas.
As I'm using Automation Anywhere, I've extracted the dynamic table in .csv and loop through each row using IF condition.
IF Item=Plan, Status=Active, will get the row number (vRowNo) and paste the vRowNo in tr[] in DOMXPath, as below:
//tbody[@id='dataTableBody']/tr[$vRowNo$]/td[4]/span[1]
Will then use Object Cloning to click on the row with DOMXPath above.

Answer (score 0):

Sure,

it's very easy, you just use keyword `and` and add another condition:

```
//tr[ td[5][.="Active"] and td[4][.="Plane"] ]
```

I've built simple js example, not sure if xpath defs would run like js implementation does but it should,

cheers

```js
const XP = '//tr[ td[5][.="Active"] and td[4][.="Plane"] ]' ;

const tr = document.evaluate( XP , document, null, XPathResult.FIRST_ORDERED_NODE_TYPE, null).singleNodeValue ;

tr.classList.add('found')
```

```css
td{ padding: 10px }
tr.found{ background: red }
```

```html
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <td>Number</td>
            <td>Color</td>
            <td>Size</td>
            <td>Item</td>
            <td>Status</td>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>55</td>
            <td>Red</td>
            <td>Small</td>
            <td>Car</td>
            <td>Active</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>243</td>
            <td>White</td>
            <td>Medium</td>
            <td>Plane</td>
            <td>Stop</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>542</td>
            <td>Blue</td>
            <td>Medium</td>
            <td>Plane</td>
            <td>Active</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>787</td>
            <td>Green</td>
            <td>Big</td>
            <td>Bike</td>
            <td>Stop</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Thanks Kresimir, you've given some ideas

Answer (score 0):

I just might have understood what you need. Just follow the below steps

1. Capture properties of any one of the rows using Object cloning command.
2. Create 2 variables. 1 - Counter, 2 - DomXPath
3. Edit the object cloning command, Keep the Domxpath property selected and remove it's value. Instead pass the DomXPath variable and Save this.
4. Go back to your task editor, Initialize counter (say '1'). and DomXPath as //tbody[@id='dataTableBody']/tr[$Counter]/td[4]/span1

Let me explain what we are doing here. When you capture an object, its properties are relevant to the object specifically. However, if you want to make this dynamic, you can do the above steps. If you pass counter as 2, it will select the second row and so on.

243 | White | Medium | Plane | Stop

542 | Blue | Medium | Plane | Active

Now that you want to click on Item with conditions - Plane | Active. You can simply increment the counter that we have defined in the above steps. And read the InnerHTML property or any other property that is giving you the text '542 | Blue | Medium | Plane | Active'. Store this in a variable. Using String operation check if the property contains "Plane | Active". If yes, you already have the counter value, that is on which line you have found your object to be clicked.

Now you just need to use object cloning command to click :)